# Swig: carrays and warning on char / char*

Tags: python, c++, swig

Swig documentation says that `array_class()` should not be used with `char` or `char *`.

http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Library.html#Library_carrays

> Note: %array_functions() and %array_class() should not be used with
>   types of char or char *.

It is not clear why. Could someone explain the reason?

Is this to avoid collisions with strings? Is it ok to use array_class with  `unsigned char *` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue in github is also asking about this problem:

https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1132

Hopefully someone will clarify the warning in the documentation.